# Does vscode buffer published messages between webview and extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

To communicate between VS Code's Webview and extension, I need to use [messaging](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview#scripts-and-message-passing).

**Does VS Code buffers messages, or do I have to create the listener before publishing a message?** The documentation seems to ignore this problem and assumes everything just works.

Comment: If you want to send a lot of messages right after the Webview create command, wait till you get a message from the Webview so you know it is created and the javascript inside webview is up and running

Comment: That's what I did, just want to know if it's necessary. This should be documented IHMO.